# Upload whole drive to a server using WinSCP in PowerShell skipping all files and folders that cannot be read

Tags: .net, powershell, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

I'm trying to copy an entire drive for example D: drive files from a Windows box to a Linux box using PowerShell and `WinSCPnet.dll`. When I try copying particular folders, I am able to copy all the files from that folder to the Linux path. But when I try to copying the entire D: drive to a Linux box folder, I am getting the following error.

> Error retrieving file list for "d:\$RECYCLE.BIN\S-1-5-21-1458064458-1966517317-3155185246-1003*.*".
>   System Error.  Code: 5.

```bsh
$transferOptions = New-Object WinSCP.TransferOptions
$transferOptions.TransferMode = [WinSCP.TransferMode]::Binary
$transferResult = $session.PutFiles("d:\*", "/tmp/some/", $False, $transferOptions)
# Throw on any error
$transferResult.Check()
```

Expected result should be that it should copy the entire D drive to the destination Linux box folder, but the above mentioned error is coming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make WinSCP .NET assembly skip all files and folders that cannot be opened by handling [`Session.QueryReceived` event](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_queryreceived):

```
# Continue on any error
$session.add_QueryReceived( { 
    Write-Host "Error: $($_.Message)"
    $_.Continue()
} )
 
$session.PutFiles("d:\*", "/tmp/some/").Check()
```

Code based on article [Recursively download directory tree with custom error handling](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_example_recursive_download_custom_error_handling#queryreceived).

---

Another option is to explicitly exclude the problematic files and folders from the transfer using [`TransferOptions.FileMask`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_transferoptions#filemask).