# WinSCP Session.SynchronizeDirectories() throws error if one or more files is being used by another process

Tags: c#, .net, winscp, winscp-net

I have a local folder `D:\test` that I want to sync with a remote server folder `/home/test`. The below code works fine in a normal case. But the problem was when I worked on one or more files from that local folder while Sync running, it throws an error and stop the Syncing.

Stack Trace:

````
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in mscorlib.dll Upload of D:\test\~$New Microsoft PowerPoint Presentation.pptx failed: 
WinSCP.SessionRemoteException: Can't open file 'D:\test\~$New Microsoft PowerPoint Presentation.pptx'.
System Error.  Code: 32.
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
Permissions of  kept with their defaults
Timestamp of  kept with its default (current time)
Exception thrown: 'WinSCP.SessionRemoteException' in WinSCPnet.dll
The thread 0x26c0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Error: WinSCP.SessionRemoteException: Can't open file 'D:\test\~$New Microsoft PowerPoint Presentation.pptx'.
System Error.  Code: 32.
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
   at WinSCP.OperationResultBase.Check()```
````

My Implementation:

```
try
{
    SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
    {
        Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,
        HostName = "hostName",
        UserName = "root",
        Password = "p@ssword",
        PortNumber = 22,
        SshHostKeyPolicy = SshHostKeyPolicy.GiveUpSecurityAndAcceptAny
    };

    using (Session session = new Session())
    {
        session.Open(sessionOptions);
        session.Timeout = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);
        session.FileTransferred += FileTransferred;
        TransferOptions transferOptions = new TransferOptions();
        transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode.Automatic;
        transferOptions.AddRawSettings("ReplaceInvalidChars", "0");
        transferOptions.ResumeSupport.State = TransferResumeSupportState.On;

        SynchronizationResult synchronizationResult;
        synchronizationResult = session.SynchronizeDirectories(SynchronizationMode.Remote, @"D:\test\", "/home/test/", true, false, SynchronizationCriteria.Time, transferOptions);
        synchronizationResult.Check();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex);
}

private static void FileTransferred(object sender, TransferEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Upload of {0} succeeded", e.FileName);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Upload of {0} failed: {1}", e.FileName, e.Error);
    }

    if (e.Chmod != null)
    {
        if (e.Chmod.Error == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Permissions of {0} set to {1}", e.Chmod.FileName, e.Chmod.FilePermissions);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Setting permissions of {0} failed: {1}", e.Chmod.FileName, e.Chmod.Error);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Permissions of {0} kept with their defaults", e.Destination);
    }

    if (e.Touch != null)
    {
        if (e.Touch.Error == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Timestamp of {0} set to {1}", e.Touch.FileName, e.Touch.LastWriteTime);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Setting timestamp of {0} failed: {1}", e.Touch.FileName, e.Touch.Error);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Timestamp of {0} kept with its default (current time)", e.Destination);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to catch the specific error and continue the syncing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make WinSCP .NET assembly skip all files and folders that cannot be opened by handling [`Session.QueryReceived` event](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_queryreceived):

```
session.QueryReceived +=
    (sender, args) => {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error: {args.Message}");
        args.Continue();
    };
```

Code based on article [Recursively download directory tree with custom error handling](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_example_recursive_download_custom_error_handling#queryreceived) and similar PowerShell question  [Upload whole drive to a server using WinSCP in PowerShell skipping all files and folders that cannot be read](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58744017/850848).

---

Another option is to explicitly exclude the problematic files and folders from the transfer using [`TransferOptions.FileMask`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_transferoptions#filemask).